# How to implement data structure using functional approach? (Linked list, tree etc)

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am new in functional programming, I learn F# and sorry if question is stupid. 
I want figure out with syntax and implement some simple data structure, but I don't know how do it.

How should look implementation of linked list? 
I tried to create type, put there mutable property and define set of methods to work with the type, but it looks like object oriented linked list...

Comment: Glad to hear that you decided to learn F#. But SO not better place for foggy question.

Comment: I strongly recommend join to the [F# Slack Team](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) and you can also ask such questions in [F# chat on SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Answer (score 4):

The basic list type in F# is already somewhat a linked list.
Though you can easily recreate a linked list with a simple union type:

```
type LinkedList<'t> = Node of 't * LinkedList<'t> | End
```

A node can have a value and a *pointer* to the next node or, be the end.
You can simply make a new list by hand:

```
Node(1, Node(2, Node(3, End))) //LinkedList<int> = Node (1,Node (2,Node (3,End)))
```

Or make a new linked list by feeding it an F# list:

```
let rec toLinkedList = function    
    | [] -> End
    | x::xs -> Node (x, (toLinkedList xs))
```

Walking through it:

```
let rec walk = function
    | End -> printfn "%s" "End"
    | Node(value, list) -> printfn "%A" value; walk list
```

The same concepts would apply for a tree structure as well.
A tree would look something like

```
type Tree<'leaf,'node> =
    | Leaf of 'leaf
    | Node of 'node * Tree<'leaf,'node> list
```

The F# Wikibook has a [good article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Advanced_Data_Structures) on data structures in F#.